# id_rsa.pub is not a public key file

Tags: ssh, openssh

I opened my public key in libre office and edited the comment section of the key and then saved. But when I run:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub
```

I get:

```
id_rsa.pub is not a public key file.
```

The file is no longer recognized as a public key file. How do I solve this?

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++ and check that libre office didn't change the formatting it is easy for programs like word and libre office to change formatting on documents and even change characters like ' in to ` just to give an example. They also tend to add random linebreaks in to files.

Comment: I didn't back up the key, so I can't compare.

Comment: delete any blank lines both before and after the populated lines of the ssh key file ... doing this fixes one source of getting that message :    `is not a public key file.`

Comment: I was puzzled by this for a while. I _think_ what happened is I copy and pasted from a terminal/tmux and this added newlines where the text was visually wrapped. I couldn't easily see this because I was looking at the text in another terminal of the same width. I ended up fixing with Kapcash's answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You should not open this file using complex text editor. Please use **Notepad++, gedit** (or any equivalent) to edit your file.
2. Then, verify you have a **space** between 'ssh-rsa' and "AAAA....." at the beginning of your key.

If you don't see anything wrong with the file and it still doesn't work, you can **regenerate your public key**.
Use the -y option as following:

```bash
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I hope it will fix your problem :)

> From `man ssh-keygen`:
>
> ```
> -y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an OpenSSH public key to stdout.
> ```

Source : [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/52285/create-a-public-ssh-key-from-the-private-key)

Comment: and make sure it is A SPACE and not a NEWLINE between "ssh-rsa" and "AAA..."